# return and error handling from an API call inside a function

Tags: php, error-handling

Is a good practice combine `return` and `error handling` inside a function?

The Api response returns success (true or false), an id from a table and a message (if has error). I also want to know why the error happened.
For example:

```
$response = [
    'success' => false,
    'message' => 'Failed to generate an id and bla bla bla',
];
```

Which one is best?

```
//1
public function store(Request $request)
    try {
        $response = $this->apiCall();
        if($response['success'] == true){
            $id = $response['id'];
            //and then Insert ``id`` in a table
        } else {
            throw new \ErrorException($response['message']);
        }
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        //But i need to know why the error happened
        dd($e); //Returns 'Failed to generate an id and bla bla bla'            
    }
}

public function apiCall()
{
    $guzzle = new Client;
    $response = $guzzle->post('https://api_url.com', [
        'form_params' => [
            'dummy' => 123,
        ],
    ]);

    return $response;
}  

//VS

//2
public function store2(Request $request)
    try {
        $id = $this->apiCall2();
        //and then Insert ``id`` in a table
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        //But i need to know why the error happened
        dd($e); //Returns 'Failed to generate an id and bla bla bla'
        
    }
}
    
public function apiCall2()
{
    $guzzle = new Client;
    $response = $guzzle->post('https://api_url.com', [
        'form_params' => [
            'dummy' => 123,
        ],
    ]);

    if($response['success'] == true){
        return $response['id'];
    } else {
        throw new \ErrorException($response['message']);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: both are ok though I would have used the first one, but I will suggest to check whether you are getting true false as boolean or in string always

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons to fail an API call and it depends on how the API developer has handled it. It is always good practice to put try-catch on API call, and you can log the error message or return it back in functions response.